# How to write a custom loss function for mulitple output keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, tf.keras

I have a multiple output keras model and currently I pass loss like this

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['mse', 'binary_crossentropy'], metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Instead of using two separate loss functions I want to combine these losses with a custom loss function of my own. This new loss function calculates the loss from a certian equation using predictied values from the two separate outputs.

For simplicity consider this as my output layers

```
out_1 = Dense(3, activation='linear')(Hlayer2)
out_2 = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(Hlayer2)
```

How do we write a custom loss function for mulitple output keras model?

Comment: Could you please give an example of such loss function? It would be good if you write it in context, i.e. using `out_1` and `out_2` tensors as well as true label tensor(s) (if applicable).

Comment: Did you read https://keras.io/losses/ ?